# Circuits/Electronics class: Thevenin Equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, thevenin

I'm trying to find the Thevenin equivalent circuit for my circuit class. I got the voltage, but am stuck on the resistance. I attached photos of the og circuit and my attempt. I'm not sure if the resistors in the broken loop don't count or if they do. I've got a feeling it's 50 ohm, because I found Ith and and divided Vth by it. So is it only the 50 ohm on the far right?

[image: my solution attempt]

Comment: Try this thought experiment.  Inject a test current into the upper righthand node, extract it from the lower righthand node, figure out how much current flows where, and use that information to calculate the voltage difference between the two righthand nodes.  The ratio of that voltage to the injected current is the Thevenin-equivalent resistance.

Comment: What if you were to replace the open connection for a resistor with a resistor that has a practically unlimited resistance. Let's say 1 mega ohm. Would you be able to calculate the resistance then? And what would the difference be between this resistor and an open connection?